# Make - Make Install and Linux update

Tags: linux, makefile

I am trying my hands new on Linux.

The following command is very useful:
    `sudo apt-get install <application>;`

As it adds the application into the linux programs list and automatically upgrades it while running the update manager.

But I would like to get more knowledge on installing the programs from the .tar.gz archives as well.

So I do:
    Extract the archive
    `./configure;`
    `make;`
    `make install;`

I have two questions in this process:
1) I read in the forum that "make install" is not good if we are updating the binaries.
So should I just do "make" and the "install" ?
2) Second question is that is there a way to add the program installed in such manner to the Linux Software Update list so that I do not have to use the terminal for every new version that is released

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Installing programs from tarballs:**

You really do not want to install packages from .tar.gz when they are in the repositories. It is much harder to update or remove it manually than you could do with `apt-get`.

If you really have to compile the program yourself use [checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) instead of `make install`. This creates a package you can install it via the package management and later remove using `apt-get`. This is much cleaner.

Also you may want to type

```
./configure && make && sudo checkinstall
```

instead of the commands you wrote. This way the program is only compiled if the configuration succeeded. The package is only built if the compilation succeeded. With `;` instead of `&&` all processes would be attempted no matter if its prerequisites are matched.

**Graphical package managers**

You can install your packages from GUI programs. Kubuntu uses for example uses `muon` for this, but the programs vary between distributions.

Comment: checkinstall has, at various points in its history, created very very bad packages. Just as a piece of information.

Comment: @EtanReisner Good to know, I have not used it in a long time, because most things are available in the repositories. If I need a more recent version I usually keep the old version on the system level and run the newer version only from my home directory.

Comment: That might have been a little FUD-y. I don't believe it has had serious problems in quite a while (though I do believe it still occasionally has minor ones).

Answer (score 0):

`make install` is "not good" if you want to be able to easily remove the files associated with a package as there is no log of the work it does and often no easy way to reverse the process. That has little to nothing to do with updating the software though (though updates can certainly run into related issues).

No, you can't add the manually compiled and installed software to your distributions list of packaged software (other than through something like checkinstall or creating a package yourself) since that's exactly what you were avoiding in the first place.

That all being said if the package exists for your distribution and you want to build it from source yourself you can often just build a more-or-less official version of the package from the distributions source package.